# How to increase the number in epic.foward() each iteration in a loop by one?

Tags: python, integer, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
epic = Turtle()
epic.color('blue', 'red')
epic.penup()
epic.goto(0,0)
epic.pd()
epic.speed(10000)
numb = 1
epic.begin_fill()
while numb == 1:
      epic.right(90)
      epic.forward(40)
      epic.right(90)
      epic.forward(40)
      epic.right(90)
      epic.forward(40)
      epic.right(90)
      epic.forward(40)
```

If I wanted the square to get bigger evenly on all four sides with each iteration of the loop, what would I add to the "while" loop in order to add one to the integer in the epic.forward() each time the loop runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for the side length, and increase it on each iteration. That would look something like this:

```
side_length = 40
while numb == 1:
    epic.right(90)
    epic.forward(side_length)
    epic.right(90)
    epic.forward(side_length)
    epic.right(90)
    epic.forward(side_length)
    epic.right(90)
    epic.forward(side_length)
    side_length += 1
```

Note that this loop, a written, will run forever, since the `numb` value you're testing in the loop condition never changes. That's *usually* not a good way to do things. If you deliberately want an infinite loop (perhaps because you're going to `break` out of it under certain conditions), then I'd suggest you use `while True`.